# Geom_smooth fitted line plot showing two legends

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a plot using geom_smooth with different color patterns. However, I am getting two legends one with blue color (solid and dashed lines) and one with two different colors (solid lines). I want the dashed and solid lines to be different colors. How can I fix this error? Here is the code and output.

```
df<-data.frame(y=rnorm(200,30,20),x=rnorm(200,20,10),treat=factor(rbinom(100,1,0.5)))
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=treat, color = treat))+
      geom_point(size = 2)+
      geom_smooth(aes(linetype=treat), se = F)+
      labs(x ="tf", y = "xm") +
      theme_bw() +
      scale_linetype_manual(values=c( "solid", "dashed"),
                    labels = c("3", "4"))+
      scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))
 p2
```

[image]

Comment: Just remove the `labels` argument in `scale_linetype_manual()`.

Comment: You set the labels 3 & 4 on one scale, but have labels 0 & 1 on the other. You'll need to give your code some logic for combining these; how would 3 and 0 get combined?

Comment: Thank you @ phil and camille. I would like to re-name the legends to 3, 4. If I remove this the output is showing as 0 and 1. I want to keep dashed and dotted lines as colors and be renamed as 3 and 4.

Comment: Then add `labels = c("3", "4")` to `scale_color_manual()`.

Comment: Thank you Phil. Here is the code line: scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"), labels = c("3", "4")). I am not getting the expected output. It is showing 2 legends

Comment: That's odd. [This is what it returned to me](https://i.imgur.com/BzRznLl.png). What version of `ggplot2` are you using?

Comment: The version is  3.2.1    @ Phil

Comment: And your last 2 lines are `scale_linetype_manual(values=c( "solid", "dashed"), labels = c("3", "4")) +  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"), labels = c("3", "4"))`?

Comment: p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=treat, color = treat))+
  geom_point(size = 2)+
  geom_smooth(aes(linetype=treat), se = F)+
  labs(x ="tf", y = "xm") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c( "solid", "dashed"))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"), labels = c("3", "4"))
    p2

Comment: The `labels` argument need to be in both `scale_*` calls.

Comment: Thank you so much @Phil. Another question,  I have a data set which contains different types of treatments (a,b,c,d) and their growth at different time points (1d, 2d, 3d) and at different concentrations (1,2,3,4). The growth values contain 3 replications each. I want to plot mean + se. My first guess I have to use dpylr package to calculate the mean and se. Can I use same code to plot the data, but would like to include mean and se. Can I use this code: geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean - se, ymax=mean + se) plus with the above code to plot the data?

Comment: If you have a different question, you should post it as a separate question

Comment: Thank you camille. I will post it as a separate question. By the way "the question how to merge color, line, style and shape legends in ggplot" did not solve the problem. But thanks to Phil who provided the solution to my question